# Object Query in MongoDB - Compass

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'd like to execute an object query about how many documents have "JAVA" in the variable L5_tecnologias:

[Screenshot with the data structure of variable L5_tecnologias](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlBl9.jpg)

As you can see in the screenshot, I use the formula shown in the MongoDB manual (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/), but it does not work. So I've tried the commands:

```
{ L5_tecnologias: { JAVA: "" } }
```

```
{ L5_tecnologias: ["JAVA"] }y
```

```
{ L5_tecnologias: "JAVA" }
```

but none of them work. Anyone can help?

Comment: share your complete query and sample BSON document instead of a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dot notation with [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/).

```
db.collection.find({
  "L5_tecnologias.JAVA": {
    $exists: true
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3upiNLaadtF)

Comment: Thanks, it works. The command in Compass would be: {"L5_tecnologias.JAVA": {$exists: true}}